# End a session so another session can begin when the user hits the browsers back button

Tags: javascript, html, session, coldfusion, session-variables

Is it possible to end a session so another session can begin when the user hits the browsers back button? I have 5 certain pages that I want this back button to end there session. I am very new to all of this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which language are u using ?

Comment: coldfusion with javascript and some html

Comment: I don't know the details but I've seen examples of people using window.history to detect if a back button was used.  Once you have that figured out, you could make an ajax call to a ColdFusion page processes the session.  I don't know the details of that either but if I tried hard enough I could probably find code samples on the internet.

Comment: better yet I could make it where the submit button from the previous page kills all previous sessions instead of trying to control the browser back button. Any examples of how to do that?

Comment: It sounds to me like whatever you're doing shouldn't perhaps be involving the user's session in the first place? Can you elaborate on how it is you came to be needing to do this? IE: what's the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Basically I have a drop down menu on the first page that redirects to 5 different pages. Each 5 of those pages is a different session. If they hit back and clicked a different value in the dropdown it would start the other session. Except it will not until the previous session is closed. So now I decided to try to figure out by making the submit button Cancel any session that may be existing so the following page can once again recreate the new session when they chose that specific value

Comment: How is that any different from using a bookmark to go back to the page with the menu?

Comment: If I can figure out the submit button to delete all sessions on submit then it will work. Those five pages are not a page anyone would ever bookmark.

Comment: It sounds like you may be misunderstanding sessions. Adam raised a good question:  "what's the problem you're trying to solve here?". Forget about sessions and CF code for a moment. What is your ultimate goal here in plain English?

Comment: Do these 5 pages have different application files?  If not, care to explain the concept of each page having different sessions?

Comment: @DB7, regarding your statement about nobody bookmarking a page, you might want to base your programming approach to deal with what's possible as opposed to what's likely.

Comment: concept is flawed in that back button doesn't necessarily cause new request to be made to server and can load page from cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <cfset StructClear(Session)>
```

This fixed the problem by inserting it on all 5 of the pages. If anyone is interested.